# Is it possible to use jQuery one() to insert content?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to use jQuery's `one()` to insert content to an element once? e.g          `$(".mainBanner").one("insertBefore or insert or append or prepend", function(){//the content});`

I havent really had a thorough mess around with the one function and I assume it should be straight forward, but have anyone of you guys had to use it for something more complicated than a `click`?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. What are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Is it possible to use jQuery's `one()` to insert content to an element once?**

No. Why would you want to? To have each method's functionality invoked **once**, simply calll it **once**:

```
$(".mainBanner").insertBefore('Some stuff');
```

---

> **have anyone of you guys had to use it for something more complicated than a `click`?**

If by 'more complicated' you mean your example (`insertBefore`, `insert`, `append`, `prepend`), then no, because they are not events. (Not sure *where* you got `insert` from, which isn't even a method...)

---

[`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) is for calling an event handler function once. After the event is triggered once, the event handler is removed.

What you are talking about is DOM manipulation. You can't call DOM manipulation methods in conjunction with `.one()`, it doesn't make any sense.

Unless you are talking about manipulating your DOM *within* the event handler function:

```
$(".mainBanner").one('EVENT NAME', function(){
    $(this).insertBefore('...');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").one("click",function(){
  $(this).animate({fontSize:"+=6px"});
  });
 });
   </script>
</head>
 <body>
```

This is a paragraph.

This is another paragraph.

Click any p element to increase its text size. The event will only trigger once for each p element.

Comment: A little explanation of what your answer is trying to show would probably help the OP.